# SNES acting weird

Tags: snes

I used to play on my SNES with a [composite cable](https://www.dhresource.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g2-M00-A9-97-rBVaGlT9DSCADRUOAAHiggIAayc444.jpg/audio-video-av-composite-cable-for-nintendo.jpg) from my brother's N64 and that worked without any problems a few years ago. Since I wanted to play some oldschool games during the holiday, I bought a new composite cable online but to my surprise, I get weird results.

I tried some Dracula and those graphics are good but after the initial intro (with some cool ominous music) the screen turns black and I can't do anything.

Dracula:
[image: Dracula]

I did the whole blowing/cleaning thing but to no avail so I tried Super Mario World but there I have some scrambled graphics. I can still play the game though but with very pixelated graphics

Super Mario World:
[image: Super Mario World]

My copy of Mario Kart and Dragon Quest V do just nothing. Since I thought it might be a cable issue, I tried the same N64 cable from my brother but that didn't help it. I also tried with an older television set but that gave the same problems.

I do have an RF cable and I tried that on both televisions but then I get simply nothing. I can't remember if the RF ever worked for that matter so it could be that that's normal behaviour but I have played the above games with this setup

I have cleaned the cartridges with a q-tip and some rubbing alcohol and also tried the trick to clean the console cartridge by using a piece of cardboard to the same size as the cartridge contact board. Put alcohol on 1 side of the cardboard and insert it in the slot a few times so it looks really clean.

I'm not really sure if it's a graphics issue since Dracula plays perfectly (except it stops after the intro) but Super Mario World has problems with the graphics and the other two simply do nothing. I can't open the console since I don't have a gamebit screwdriver but is there any way I can determine which may be the error in these games?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing scrambled graphics on SNES console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13550/fixing-scrambled-graphics-on-snes-console)

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I saw that question but the person has graphic problems with each and every cartridge. That's different from mine since Dracula for instance works perfectly but stops after the intro movie

Comment: it may be possible that the scrambled graphics is due to the N64 and SNES having a different screen size and it attempts to scale.

Comment: But I have the issue with both cables. And it did work on this tv with the N64 cable

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting a shim between the cartridge and the chassis door to make sure that the contacts are touching consistently. Over time i think the contacts lose stiffness and need to be coaxed.

Comment: What do you mean? Insert a piece of carton in the SNES itself where the contact of the cartridge connects?

Comment: Pardon the real crude cutaway of an snes. The red arrow points to the shim, which is pushing forward slightly on the cartridge from behind. https://imgur.com/a/a7Sgr

Comment: Could you name it on this picture? https://m.imgur.com/DocSWan

Comment: Could you check my previous comment?